# Connector for washing machine to kitchen faucet

Tags: plumbing, faucet, washing-machine

I don't have a standard faucet but one that extends out. What is the correct dimension of the adapter? I tried a few but none of them really fits.

[image: kitchen faucet]

[image: washing machine]

Comment: do you want to install a T split

Comment: Why are you trying to connect the washing machine to a kitchen tap? The top connector is a standard shower hose fitting, the bottom is a standard washing machine fixture. It's designed to attach permanently to a specific hose-point, probably behind the kitchen units… on the wall behind the gap the washer fits in...

Comment: @Tetsujin we will have a baby soon and trying to put a small washing machine in the kitchen for quick wash.

Comment: @Ruskes anything that is quick and easy

Comment: when looking for a adapter pay attention to the slope of the tread part. For hoses they are not sloped, if sloped it is not for hose, If it screws on only 1 or 2 turns it is sloped.

Comment: You're looking for a 'shower hose to washing machine adaptor'…  though each is a standard fitting, I can't find one.

Comment: Unless you have a washer that is specifically made to be attached to a sink faucet, you probably cannot find a shower to washer hose adapter because there are none, because this is never done and is a bad idea.

Comment: Would this work for you: Dishwasher,washer Snap Coupling Adapter,shower hose, garden hose(3/4GHT)quick connection, for Bathroom/kitchen,sink to hose adapter Faucet Hose Adapter,Sink Quick-fit Attachment (Quick-Connect) https://a.co/d/dpBmmmR

Comment: @Ruskes in the last image it says it won't work for pull out faucets

Comment: I was wondering why do you want to connect it at the pull out point, if the washer hose is under the cabinet.

Comment: read this https://kilbasar.wordpress.com/2014/08/25/connecting-a-portable-dishwasher-to-a-pull-down-faucet-hose/

Comment: @Ruskes because I need an option to take it out after the wash. It shouldn't be permanent

Comment: Then you have to deal with the multiple parts solution I posted, but you can use quick disconnect for the washer hose and leave the rest. If you liked it, I can make it a answer for you to accept my work

Answer (score 2):

I ordered bunch of cheap adapters from aliexpress, and the 3/4 male (washer pipe) - 1/2 male (faucet) fits perfectly.

[image]

Comment: Next step may be to get a snap-fitting adapter, so you can easily connect and disconnect that hose. This used to be common for apartment dwellers who had a washing machine but didn't have taps specifically provided to connect it to; my parents had that setup while my younger sib was in diapers.